# How to include the size of array into the for loop without triggering error

Tags: c

This is the login function that I want to implement.

The problem is that I want to use the syntax of sizeof(id) in the for loop without triggering error.

Any solution??

```
int login();

int login()
{
    int i, att, num_i, status;
    att = 1;
    status = 0;
    num_i = 999;
    char* id[100], * pass[100];
    char* inp_id[100], inp_pass[100];
    id[0] = "id1"; ///Sample ID
    id[1] = "id2";
    id[2] = "id3";
    pass[0] = "pass1"; ///Sample pass 
    pass[1] = "pass2";
    pass[2] = "pass3";
    while (att <= 3)
    {
        printf("ID:");
        scanf("%s", &inp_id);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) /// I wanted this to repeat accordingly to the size of ID that was stored
        {
            if (strcmp(inp_id, id[i]) == 0) /// Cuz when I declare i > 100 when it call for i[4] and it doesn't exist, error occured.
            {
                num_i = i;
                break; /// wanted it to break out of the loop once it got the id that's similar to what was entered
            }
        }
        printf("Password:");
        scanf("%s", &inp_pass);
        if (num_i < 100)
        {
            if (strcmp(inp_pass, pass[num_i]) == 0)///checking pass according to the positon of i on the ID
            {
                status = 1;
                att = 999;
            }
        }
        att++;
    }
```

I've deleted a portion of the code due to it asking for more  information.

Comment: Try a different approach. A more normal way of doing something like this is to define a struct with login entries, then declare an array with a NULL entry at the end, and use a while loop to go over them.

Comment: can I trouble you to write those? I don't quite understand what you're trying to explain.

Comment: Defining a structure with login entries. Which part do I need to change? I'm a beginner at programming so I'm sorry if I asked obvious questions.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example of what I described in my comment:
Or at least these are components to help you understand.

```
struct account {
    char *id;
    char *pass;
};

static const struct account account_list[] = {
    { .id = "id1", .pass = "pass1" },
    { .id = "id2", .pass = "pass2" },
    { .id = "id3", .pass = "pass3" },
    { NULL },
};

struct account *a;

for (a = account_list; a.id; a++) {
    ....
}
```

Something like this is much easier to work with.

Comment: After trying it, I'm more confused. What does the "a" for?
struct account *a;